# Android listview adapter check if it contains a string

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello i am kind of new to programming in android so far day by day am managing to learn something new but at times i do get stuck , today i am working on a simple project with listview and a button to check if it contains a specific string in the listview.

here is my code

```
private ListView listView1 ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blockcontact);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView1 );
        Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        list.add("07474715336");
        list.add("+61470405818");
        list.add("470105848");
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String strName = "+61470405818";
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                    if (strName.equals(list)) {

                        CharSequence text = "found";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();

                    } else

                        context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "not found";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
        });

 listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

am trying to check if this number exist
 String strName = "+61470405818";

the list may contain large numbers so i want to first loop through the list and then check using index if the item exist or not.

Comment: I was thinking an answer but it almost involves to fix almost all your code. I recommend you to take a look to Java Basis and Android Basis before going deeper with them.

Comment: i want to say thanks for you comment taking your time in replying i will appreciate it if you can just help me do what i need because i spend hours looking for an answer .   i am a vb6 and .net programmer and i am a quick learner i am trying to learn its not like am asking you or anybody to write the entire code if i have made any mistakes or done something wrong please correct my code by showing me its all i want cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the items inside the list with your target String.

So instead of:

```
strName.equals(list);
```

use:

```
strName.equals((String)listView1.getAdapter().getItem(i));
```

Comment: @Josheph82 I thought the same as you, but if you analyze the code... It seems to me that curls are wrong and some pieces of code won't what she want. Maybe this won't be enough right?

Comment: the code above just adds 3 items in listview , just by a button click i want to check if these string exist thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a function to check an arrayadapter for contains and if I don't want dups I don't add dups.

```
private boolean DoesmBTArrayAdapterContain(String nameAndAddr)
{
    if(null==mBTArrayAdapter)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<mBTArrayAdapter.getCount();i++)
    {
        String s = mBTArrayAdapter.getItem(i);
        if(s.equals(nameAndAddr))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```